# In android emulator video doesn't show (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, video, emulation

**My problem is that the video works fine on web view but doesn't show or work in the Android emulator. I want to play this video in an emulator also. And all the videos are asset videos. If anyone knows the solution or if anyone can help please help. Thank You**

**Below is the code which I wrote for the video **

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:cached_video_player/cached_video_player.dart';


class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoApp> createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'assets/videos/animation 1 final.mp4',
    );

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              } else {
                // If the video is paused, play it.
                _controller.play();
              }
            });
          },
          // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X0OX.png][1]

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling from `network` but giving an `asset` path.

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
  'assets/videos/animation 1 final.mp4',
);
```